# C# - How to disable all events on WPF form

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events

I have a lot of `ToggleSwitch` and `Combobox` controls in my application, I am setting them up on application startup, which fires all the events associated with those controls.

These events are supposed to fire only when the user interacts with the controls and not when the value is changed programmatically.

Is there a way to disable all the events and reactivate them afterwards?

I didn't find any efficient solution on other posts or on the Internet.

Comment: I'm not aware any way to do this. but the need to do this might point to a bad architecture.

Comment: you can add a flag and rise it after you finish programmatically push.
in the event Handler you do if(flag){}else{}

Comment: What if you just declare a boolean set to false, that you will switch to true at the end of the startUp. You can check in your custome event the value, if it's false they just return

Comment: Already thought about this solution but it means a lot of conditions. If i have 100 events it makes 100 test. I was looking for something less messy.

Comment: Well... 100 hundred events IS messy... ;-) As Alex said, this is a clue pointing to bad design

Comment: What do you mean setting them up? Do you not use `XAML` and not care at all about `event`s?

Comment: I wouldn't consider 100 checks (especially such trivial ones) "messy". Apart from that, do these events being raised have any real impact on your application, or are you just trying to optimize your code upfront? If it is an issue, I don't think raising these events is the problem, but rather what your handlers do, so perhaps a good place to start would be to defer subscription to these event (by, for exapmle, creating a subscription queue, which would realize them once the application is "set up").

Comment: To keep long story short - there is no way to disable event raising in _.NET_, let alone to narrow it only to _WPF_ related ones.

Comment: @ALex and Bruno you said it might be a bad design issue. I have on my UI 10 checkbox and 10 combobox how do you catch user interaction if not with events ?

Comment: @Grx70 They have an impact because everytime a combobox item is changed or a checkbox is checked it has to communicate with a serial device. So at application startup when i get all the parameter of the serial device to set up my ComboBoxes and everything, it is triggering all the events related to these controls and sending unnecessary data to the serial device. Which makes the process of reading my serial device parameters slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling all events isn't possible because there are many event handlers in the framework that you have no direct control over. The fact you want to do this at all suggests that your design is flawed.

You can detect the difference between user interaction and programmatic change with a bit of plumbing and the diligence to use it everywhere that it matters. Suppose you have a `ComboBox`, and you want to detect when the user triggers [`SelectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx). This can be done with a flag, set only when you make programmatic changes. i.e.

```
private bool blockHandlers;

// Wrapped in a method for convenience.
public void SetSelectedIndex(int index)
{
    blockHandlers = true;
    comboBox.SelectedIndex = index;
    blockHandlers = false;
}

private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (blockHandlers) return;

    // Your event handling code...
}
```

Using this technique requires that you **always** either use `SetSelectedIndex` or set/reset `blockHandlers` around programmatic changes to ensure event handler(s) observe it and do nothing.

Comment: I will look for other ways to do it and if none of them satisfying for my purpose I think i will just go with that.

Comment: Somewhat offtopic remark: The general consensus between me and coworkers is to name such a bool switch by its effect (`blockEvents`) rather than the description of why it needs to be switched (`isSelfUpdating`), because there may be several reasons to flick the switch.

Answer (score 3):

As some have said, this smells of bad architecture and that you would even want to do this in the first place, but there is a way you can "block" events using an if statement and a simple boolean.

First, you'll want to declare a field in your class.

```
private bool _blockHandlers;
```

Once you've done that, you just set the bool to true where you want to start blocking handler, probably in your class constructor if its straight away. As I don't know the name of your class I won't go there.

But lets say you have an event handler

```
private void SomeHandler
{
    if (blockHandlers) 
    {
        return;
    }

    // It's not blocked, lets continue...
}
```

This way, you can temporarly block handlers or permenantly block them, with this method you just simple check if they're blocked, if not you can continue with your handler.

Comment: upvote for the ability to only temporary disable them.

Comment: Aside from mentioning that it's a code smell, how is this any different from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I come up with more elegant solution for this problem.

I created the following helper class:

```cs
public class WpfEventExecutor
{

    bool isLoaded = false;
    bool isProcessingEvent = false;

    public void SetLoaded()
    {
        isLoaded = true;
    }

    public void Execute(Action action)
    {
        if (!isLoaded) return;
        if (isProcessingEvent) return;
        isProcessingEvent = true;
        action();
        isProcessingEvent = false;
    }
}
```

GeneralView.xaml:

```xml
<Page x:Class="MyApp.UI.Settings.Views.GeneralView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:ui="http://schemas.modernwpf.com/2019"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.UI.Settings.Views"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Title="GeneralItem">

    <StackPanel>

        <ui:ToggleSwitch Name="StartWithWindowsCheckbox" Toggled="StartWithWindowsCheckbox_OnToggled" Header="Start with Windows" />

        <Line Height="20" />

        <TextBlock>Language</TextBlock>
        <ComboBox Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <ComboBoxItem Selected="EnglishBoxItem_OnSelected" Name="EnglishBoxItem">English</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Selected="ChineseBoxItem_OnSelected" Name="ChineseBoxItem">简体中文</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>

    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

GeneralView.cs:

```cs
using System.Windows;
using MyApp.Helpers;
using Page = System.Windows.Controls.Page;

namespace MyApp.UI.Settings.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for GeneralItem.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class GeneralView : Page
    {
        
        readonly WpfEventExecutor eventExecutor = new WpfEventExecutor();

        public GeneralView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            StartWithWindowsCheckbox.IsOn = LogicHelpers.IsStartWithWindows();


            switch (MyApp.Settings.Values.General.Language)
            {
                case MyApp.Settings.GeneralType.LanguageType.English:
                    EnglishBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
                    break;
                case MyApp.Settings.GeneralType.LanguageType.Chinese:
                    ChineseBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
                    break;
            }

            // Call this method only after you finished to change the elements programmatically
            // After calling to this method, we assume that each time the elements values changed,
            // it caused by the user and not via code
            eventExecutor.SetLoaded();

        }



        void StartWithWindowsCheckbox_OnToggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            eventExecutor.Execute(() =>
            {
                // This is safe section where to process the event.
                // This way, the event will not call itself and we prevent stackoverflow error
            
                // Your code is here
            });
        }

        void EnglishBoxItem_OnSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            eventExecutor.Execute(() =>
            {
                // This is safe section where to process the event.
                // This way, the event will not call itself and we prevent stackoverflow error
            
                // Your code is here
            });
        }

        void ChineseBoxItem_OnSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            eventExecutor.Execute(() =>
            {
                // This is safe section where to process the event.
                // This way, the event will not call itself and we prevent stackoverflow error
            
                // Your code is here
            });
        }
    }
}
```